# How to manipulate files by ffmpeg in Android 31: permission denied

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg in my android app. So I want to test it if it works before moving on. I use an external library : [github link](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android) 
The code looks like this :

```java
package net.omidn.aslanmediaconverter;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.ExecuteCallback;
import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegKit;
import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.FFmpegSession;
import com.arthenica.ffmpegkit.Session;

import net.bramp.ffmpeg.job.FFmpegJob;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    FFmpegJob myjob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);


        FFmpegJob job = null;

        File inFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/video_2021-05-29_17-50-20.mp4");
        String inputName = Uri.fromFile(inFile).toString();
        Log.d(TAG, inputName);
        Log.d(TAG,"file exists : " + String.valueOf(inFile.exists()));
        Log.d(TAG,"file canRead : " + String.valueOf(inFile.canRead()));

        FFmpegSession fFmpegSession = FFmpegKit.executeAsync("-i file:///storage/emulated/0/video_2021-05-29_17-50-20.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 file:///storage/emulated/0/out.mp4",
                new ExecuteCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(Session session) {

                    }
                });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textView.setText("" + fFmpegSession.getState().name() + "    " + fFmpegSession.getOutput());
    }

}
```

As you can see I give the files with `file:///` protocol. If I don't use that the resault is the same. The three lines of `Log.d(...)` will print :

```
2021-06-03 00:58:08.869 8376-8376/net.omidn.aslanmediaconverter D/MainActivity: file:///storage/emulated/0/video_2021-05-29_17-50-20.mp4
2021-06-03 00:58:08.869 8376-8376/net.omidn.aslanmediaconverter D/MainActivity: file exists : true
2021-06-03 00:58:08.869 8376-8376/net.omidn.aslanmediaconverter D/MainActivity: file canRead : false
```

The video file has read access on the storage :
[image: The video file has read access]

Comment: Can read returns false. Android 10 device?

Comment: @blackapps Yes the API number of the device is 29;

Comment: You should request legacy external storage in manifest.

Comment: i faced same problem with same repo and same error just some days ago and what i tried is that, i first saved my file in app specific folder (in `Android/data/app_folder/cache/output_file`) and then moved output file to new location using `InputStream` and `OutputStream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this from [the libraries](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android) wiki page.

I will quote it here:

If you want to use a file selected using Storage Access Framework (SAF) with `FFmpegKit`, you can use the following methods to convert a `Uri` to a file path defined with `FFmpegKit`'s saf: protocol. That path can be safely used as input or output in `FFmpegKit` and `FFprobeKit` commands.

**Input**

```java
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String inputPath = FFmpegKitConfig.getSafParameterForRead(requireContext(), uri);
FFmpegKit.execute("-i " + inputPath + " ... output.mp4");
```

**Output**

```java
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String outputPath = FFmpegKitConfig.getSafParameterForWrite(requireContext(), uri);
FFmpegKit.execute("-i input.mp4 ... " + outputPath);
```

[The wiki page on GitHub](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Storage-Access-Framework)